# Enabe/Disable javascript in Chrome using selenium in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-chromedriver

I want to disable and enable JavaScript using selenium in C#. I am using Chrome driver. I have searched a lot but I could not find anything. Most of the codes are for Firefox or By another programming language like python. But I could not find anything for Chrome in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable javascript by adding an argument to your options. It will look like this:

```
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();         
     options.AddArgument("--enable-javascript");
```

Comment: of course, you need to add an options parameter inside the driver. 

 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"/users/chrome/Driver/Path", options);